# The development server returned response error code: 500 in react native when connect to firebase by installing firebase

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I try to connect to `firebase` by `react native`.
Here is code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View} from 'react-native'
import Card from './card'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "tinderclone-99d8e.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "tinderclone-99d8e",
  storageBucket: "tinderclone-99d8e.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "264605926507",
  appId: "1:264605926507:web:c9309a6669322ef6839d2e",
  databaseURL:''
  
};


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    profileIndex: 0,
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref().child('users').once('value', (snap) => {
      console.log('Data', snap.val())
    })
  }


  nextCard = () => {
    this.setState({profileIndex: this.state.profileIndex + 1})
  }

  render() {
    const {profileIndex} = this.state
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        {profiles.slice(profileIndex, profileIndex + 3).reverse().map((profile) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={profile.id}
              profile={profile}
              onSwipeOff={this.nextCard}
            />
          )
        })}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const profiles = [
  {
    id: '259389830744794',
    name: 'Candice',
    birthday: '10/18/1986',
    bio: 'Supermodel',
  },
  {
    id: '720115413',
    name: 'Alessandra',
    birthday: '1/10/1989',
    bio: 'Dancer',
  },
  {
    id: '169571172540',
    name: 'Miranda',
    birthday: '12/12/1983',
    bio: 'Doctor',
  },
  {
    id: '1476279359358140',
    name: 'Alissa',
    birthday: '2/11/1990',
    bio: 'Comedian',
  },
  {
    id: '1140849052644433',
    name: 'Behati',
    birthday: '3/23/1991',
    bio: 'Developer',
  },
  {
    id: '912478262117011',
    name: 'Rosie',
    birthday: '9/4/1989',
    bio: 'Artist',
  },
  {
    id: '173567062703796',
    name: 'Kendall',
    birthday: '8/17/1992',
    bio: 'Truck Driver',
  },
]
```

here is database

[image]

here is error

```
While trying to resolve module `firebase` from file `C:\Users\PC\Desktop\de\App.js`, the package `C:\Users\PC\Desktop\de\node_modules\firebase\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\PC\Desktop\de\node_modules\firebase\index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

I already install `firebase` by `npm`
I try to `run npm install` and npm start again by searching others answers
their answer not work for me .
in 2021 , `firebase` is not same as before .
I dont know how can solve this problem
can someone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You importing `import * as firebase from 'firebase'` in the top of your file..Try to import this line and tell me if it works.
`import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";`

Some paths of the `firebase` have changed a long time ago so if you are watching legacy code snipets maybe you will have errors.

Comment: thanks ,This is correct import .after that I import import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'.when render show error is 'app2.default.database is not function.need to import this database ?

Comment: try to import `import "firebase/compat/auth"` and `import "firebase/compat/firestore"` if you are using firebase auth too and firestore too

Comment: I am not using auth and firestore .error is pointing to ```componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref().child('users').once('value', (snap) => {
      console.log('Data', snap.val())
    })
  }```

Comment: import are as follow ```import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'```

Comment: I also check documentation , there is no special about this using ```firebase.database().ref()```.

Comment: import `import database from '@react-native-firebase/database'` if you are using react-native firebase. and maybe need the imports above to change